# Excel VBA - Check if connected to internet AND if its via Wifi or Ethernet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to alert users before running a macro which takes a lot longer if run on Wifi as opposed to the company LAN.

---

I have found the following code:

[Checking for internet connection using VBA](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-check-internet-connectivity.html#P8djz6QY785Mde3B.99)

The following code snippet uses API functions to check Internet connectivity and also the type of connection
:

```
Public Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState _
                         Lib "wininet.dll" (lpdwFlags As Long, _
                                            ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedStateEx Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetGetConnectedStateExA" ( _
ByRef lpdwFlags As Long, _
ByVal lpszConnectionName As String, _
ByVal dwNameLen As Long, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long


'Local system uses a modem to connect to the Internet.
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM As Long = &H1

'Local system uses a LAN to connect to the Internet.
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN As Long = &H2

'Local system uses a proxy server to connect to the Internet.
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY As Long = &H4

The following API functions are used

Function IsConnected() As Boolean

    Dim Stat As Long

    IsConnected = (InternetGetConnectedState(Stat, 0&) <> 0)

    If IsConnected And INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN Then
        MsgBox "Lan Connection"
    ElseIf IsConnected And INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM Then
        MsgBox "Modem Connection"
    ElseIf IsConnected And INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY Then
        MsgBox "Proxy"
    End If
End Function
```

If you want to know just if it is connected or not you can use the following:

```
CBool(InternetGetConnectedStateEx(0, vbNullString, 512, 0&))
```

---

This tells me I have a LAN connection, but it does so whether I am on WIFI or connected to the LAN. I need to distinguish between them.

Does anyone know how I can do this please?

Cheers

Comment: How did you you go? Did you get it working?

Comment: @KyloRen - i think your solution worked ! thank you. see comment below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, It loops through each connection and gets the `ID` , `AdapterType` and `ConnectionStatus`. Just use the one you need.

```
Dim oObject
Dim adapter
Dim item

Set oObject = GetObject("WINMGMTS:\\.\ROOT\cimv2")

Set adapter = oObject.InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapter")

    For Each item In adapter

        If item.NetconnectionID <> "null" Then
         Debug.Print item.NetconnectionID
         Debug.Print item.AdapterType
         Debug.Print item.NetConnectionStatus
     End If
    Next
```

Thanks to to @tom preston, a link to [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: +1 Great response.  for completeness, the NetworkConnectionStatus etc can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response i think this works :). I take it a netconnectionstatus of 2 means connected? I tested it with wifi and LAN. I added 'And item.NetConnectionStatus = 2 Then ....' to isolate the connected interface